# Can we implement both @pathparam and @queryparam for the same endpoint

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am teaching myself REST API development. As part of this, I am creating a Java web server. However, I am stuck on something, and don't know how to proceed.

I have an endpoint called `/users`, through which users will `GET` the data. However, I want to implement the option of finding a user and limiting the number of users returned. For example:

- `GET /users/300` should return the user with ID 300.
- If I get the query `GET /users?count=10`, I want to limit the return to 10 users.

For this, I have settled on the using `@QueryParam` and `@PathParam`. The question is: Can I use both of them in the same method?

For example:

```
@Path("/User") 
@Produces({"application/json"})
public List<User> getUsers() {
    // ...
}

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public JSONObject getUserwithId(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return jsonObjectwithId;
}

@Path("?count")
public JSONObject getUserwithCount(@QueryParam("count") int count) {
    return noOfusers;
}
```

I want to whether this is possible.

Comment: You should be able to use the @QueryParam and PathParam. I dont see that there is any restriction as such .

Comment: One change i can see is rather than this ...you could write <pre><code> @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public JSONObject getUserwithId(@PathParam("id") int id,@QueryParam("count") int count)  </code></pre>  I dont see a reason for having two different methods

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have done this before on web services I have personally worked on. It's not that common, since REST interfaces just don't usually merit the needed complexity. But, it is perfectly permissible for `@QueryParam` and `@PathParam` to be used by the same method. I see that you are using Jersey. Based on [this thread](https://coderanch.com/t/639755/java/PathParam-QueryParam-working-added-resource), if you are actually using Jersey 1.x, you may need to upgrade if you are currently having issues.

Comment: I choose to divide the two into different objects and it is working. Appreciate the response.